# Array with random numbers only contains the same values?

Tags: c

I wrote a program which should create many random numbers and save it in an array. I also checked up many questions and everyone just saying to set seed one time but that does not solve my problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

void printArray(int *arr){
    for(int i = 0; arr[i] != '\0'; i++){
        printf("%i, ", *arr);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // set seed
    srand(time(NULL));
    int number_max; 

    // first argument
    int arg1 = atoi(argv[1]);

    if(arg1 <= 4){
        printf("number to small or not a number\n");
        return 0;
    }
    // 2^n space for random numbers
    number_max = pow(2, arg1);

    // initialize array
    int numbers[number_max];

    // create 2^n random numbers from 0 to 10000
    for(int i = 0; i < number_max; i++){
        numbers[i] = (rand() % (10000 - 0 + 1)) + 0; 
    }

    // print Array
    printArray(numbers);
}
```

That is my code. My whole array contains the same value. I understand the problem, but don't know how to solve.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: `printf("%i, ", *arr);` you're printing the same value all the time.

Comment: As a general debug technique - if something is not working with random numbers, try hardcoding some fixed values first.

Comment: Iam so stupid sorry :/

Comment: I have a déjà lu. Have I seen exactly the same question with exactly the same root cause recently?

Answer (score 3):

Few things:

1. Your loop condition `for (int i = 0; arr[i] != '\0'; i++)` requires that the array is terminated with zero. This is not the case unless you explicitly terminate the array with zero. Also, if any of the values in `numbers` is zero, it will stop there.
2. You are always dereferencing the first element in the array. Print `arr[i]` or `*(arr + i)` to print the actual array values one by one.
3. Not code related, but it's grammatically correct to say "number too small", not "number to small". :-)

Answer (score 1):

You see same values because you are printing same element `*arr`, which is equivalent to `arr[0]`.

Maybe you want this:

```
void printArray(int *arr){
    for(; *arr != '\0'; arr++){
        printf("%i, ", *arr);
    }
}
```

or this:

```
void printArray(int *arr){
    for(int i = 0; arr[i] != '\0'; i++){
        printf("%i, ", *(arr + i));
    }
}
```

or this:

```
void printArray(int *arr){
    for(int i = 0; arr[i] != '\0'; i++){
        printf("%i, ", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Note that you can write simply `0` instead of `'\0'`.

Comment: However, there is no guarantee that the array contains a 0.